# Using custom \locallabels command with custom \eqref command

Tags: cross-referencing

I am trying to restrict refs' and labels' scopes to certain sections of a LaTeX document. Cf. [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82115/5764).

I have a custom `\locallabels{}` command, modified from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82115/5764), and a custom `\eq{}` command:

```
\documentclass{article}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\origref\ref \let\origpageref\pageref \let\origlabel\label \let\origeqref\eqref \newcommand\locallabels[1]{%
    \renewcommand\label[1]{\origlabel{#1##1}}% ← notice the change here:
    \renewcommand\ref[1]{\origref{#1##1}}% ##1#1, not #1##1
    \renewcommand\pageref[1]{\origpageref{#1##1}}%
    \renewcommand\eqref[1]{\origeqref{#1##1}}%
  }}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\eq}[1]{\eqref{eq:#1}}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\label{sec}

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:1}
  \int3x+4\pi\,dx
\end{equation} 

\eq{1} should give (1), but it actually gives (2).

\locallabels{:sec2}
\section{Section 2}
\label{sec2}

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:1}
  \int6x+3y\,dx
\end{equation} 

\eq{1} should give (2), but it gives "(??)".

\end{document}
```

Why do I get unresolved references, "(??)" for the second `\eq{1}`? Why do I get "(1)" for the first `\eq{1}`?

UPDATE: I discovered that `hyperref` (not included in the above MWE) complicates things. See [the comments below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135883/using-custom-locallabels-command-with-custom-eqref-command#comment307418_135995).

Also, how would I define a command that would turn off `\locallabels{}`'s effect for a certain reference. E.g., this doesn't work:

```
\newcommand{\refnolocallabels}[2]{\locallabels{}\ref{#1}\locallabels{#2}}
```

thanks

Comment: The main problem is that `amsmath` redefines `\label` itself.

Comment: @egreg: So, how would I redefine `\label` after `amsmath` redefines it? thanks

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two independent problems here: as mentioned in the comments `amsmath` internally uses its own definition of `\label` and assigns its meaning only inside the display environments. So the trick with changing `\label`at the outside doesn't work. Instead one has to provide a redefinition for `\label@in@display` as well (which is the `amsmath` internal).

The second problem is of a different nature: in the command `\locallabels` there is a redefinition for `\ref` and one for `\eqref`. But there should be only one for `\ref` as `\eqref` internally calls `\ref` in the end. With both redefnitions the call to `\eq{1}` is applying `:sec2` twice and of course that results in a label that was never defined.

So in summary the correct code is

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\origlabel@in@display\label@in@display
  \let\origref\ref \let\origpageref\pageref \let\origlabel\label
%  \let\origeqref\eqref
  \newcommand\locallabels[1]{%
    \renewcommand\label[1]{\origlabel{#1##1}}% ← notice the change here:
    \renewcommand\ref[1]{\origref{#1##1}}%
    \renewcommand\pageref[1]{\origpageref{#1##1}}%
%    \renewcommand\eqref[1]{\origeqref{#1##1}}%
    \renewcommand\label@in@display[1]{\origlabel@in@display{#1##1}}%
  }}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Okay, now I get some strange problem when using your code code in my original document (not in the MWE above). `\eq{1}` in that document gives things like this: "(6.1Section name.6.1)." Also, mustn't `#1##1` really be `##1#1` in my case because my custom `\eq{}` command is "postfix," since, e.g., `\eq{1}` = `\eqref{eq:1:sec2}` and not `\eqref{:sec2eq:1}` or something else? thanks

Comment: I'm still getting the strange "(6.1Section name.6.1)" issue. Clearly, the references match up, but I have no clue why it displays "(6.1Section name.6.1)" and not just "(6.1)". Also, `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` should isolate `\locallabels` from other packages possibly interfering with it, shouldn't it?

Comment: Also, I get no errors or warning compiling my original (non MWE) document.

Comment: a) \makeatother is only there to allow for using commands with @ in the name, nothing else. b) fairly sure that you are not supposed to change the order #1##1, I think you have a bit of a misunderstanding when things get applied. c) log in the aux file to see what labels are really generated. d) the "section name" in the ref sounds like you use some additional package but there is no way to guess what other packages you have that influence your label ref setup.

Comment: Here's what I see in my .aux file: `\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {6.1}Section name.}{81}{section.6.1}}
\newlabel{part2:2.ch1.sec1}{{6.1}{81}}
\newlabel{part2:eq:1}{{6.1}{82}{Section name.\relax }{equation.6.1}{}}`

Comment: I discovered hyperref is what's causing the problems!

Comment: @Geremia: Of course, yet you never included that in your MWE! [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)'s sole purpose is to manage references - something you're trying to change. So it is integral in the analysis, debugging and solution.

Comment: @Werner: Fortunately, I can do without `hyperref`.

Comment: If you load hyperref *before* the \AtBeginDocument then it is likely to work (it does with your original MWE) but of course there may be other factors like options to hyperref.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach: No, loading it before didn't help. It must be my publisher's stylesheet does something else with hyperref etc. Also, did you see my question in the OP about defining a  `\refnolocallabels`? thanks again

Comment: as mentioned in the answer to the original question all you have to do is to use \origref in place of \ref to get a non-local reference. However, your code should work too as far as I can tell without testing, it is only a bit too complicated to be useful. If it doesn't then it might be better to start a new question with a full MWE.

Comment: I get duplicates like this: `part2:part2:eq:80bisb`, which then end up being undefined… Is this due to running latex multiple times?

Comment: Thanks for this very helpful answer, @FrankMittelbach! One clarification question regarding line 8 of your code: `\renewcommand\ref[1]{\origref{#1##1}}% ##1#1, not #1##1`. The code says `#1##1` but the comment says `##1#1, not #1##1`. Can you please clarify which one is correct?

Comment: @CL. ..5 year later ... I haven't written the comment, it was in the original posters code, I just corrected his code (in other places) and overlooked that the comment makes no sense. I'll remove it

Comment: @FrankMittelbach 5 years, yes. But still incredibly helpful ...! This seems to be exactly what many PhD students need when "combining" several papers (with identical labels) into a single thesis document. Thanks for the clarification!